# Probability of Type 1 Error when using $X_{min}$ as a test static

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X_1,X_2, ..., X_{15}$ be a random sample from the exponential distribution with $\lambda > 0 $. To test $H_0 : \lambda = 1/5$ versus $H_A : \lambda < 1/5$ use $X_{min}$ as a test statistic. If $X_{min} \geq 1$ reject the null hypothesis.

My problem is then to compute the probability of a type 1 error. I know that I have to calculate

$$\begin{align*}
  P(\text{Type 1 Error}) & = P(\text{Reject} \ H_0 \ | \ H_0 \ \text{True}) \\
  & = P(X_{min} \geq 1 \ | \ \lambda = 1/5) \\
  & = 
\end{align*}
$$

However, I am not sure how to proceed now. As a hint in my book, I have to look an exercise where the PDF for $x_{min}$ is found. Do I have to find the pdf for $X_{min}$ now? I know that the PDF for $x_{min}$
is
$$
f_{min}(x) = n(1 - F(x))^{n-1}f(x)
$$
Do I have to use this? Furthermore, is there any way to calculate this probability with in r studio?

All help is appreciated.

TIA.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be on track.  Yes, you use that formula for the pdf of $X_{min}$. Books seem to disagree on what to use for the parameter of an exponential.  Does your definition have $\lambda = \mu$ or $\frac{1}{\lambda} = \mu$?  I will use the latter in what follows.

Since $F(x) = 1-e^{-5x}$,

$1-F(x) = e^{-5x}$ and $(1-F(x))^{n-1} = (e^{-5x})^{14} = e^{-70x}$.
So $f_{min} = 14e^{-70x}\cdot 5 e^{-5x} = 70e^{-75x}$
So $P(X_{min} > 1) = \int_{1}^{\infty}70e^{-75x}dx$

Comment: Thx for the help. I tried to use $\lambda = 1/5$ instead and got $P(X_{min} \geq 1 = \int _1^{\infty }\:\frac{3}{e^{3x}}\cdot  = \:0.04978$ but I am not sure how to calculate the conditional probability? Because if I used your calculations I got $P(X_{min} \geq 1) = \:2.50006E-33$ which I don't think is right?

Comment: Is this correct?$$\begin{align*}
  P(\text{Type 1 Error}) & = P(\text{Reject} \ H_0 \ | \ H_0 \ \text{True}) \\
  & = P(X_{min} \geq 1 \ | \ \lambda = 1/5) \\
  & = \frac{\int_1^\infty \frac{3}{e^{3x}} dx}{\int_0^\infty 1/5e^{-1/5x}dx} \\
  & = 0.04978
  
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Yes that is right.  The denominator equals $1$, which is why it doesn't matter if you divide by it or not.  That's just the normalization condition for a probability density.

Comment: Thanks Robert. Could I also use the argument that because $X_i$ for $i  = 1,2,,,.,15$ is i.d.d, thus $P(A | B) = P(A)$?

Comment: $H_0$ being true is necessary for the calculations to be valid in the first place.  We don't know $P(H_0$ is true). So you don't have to use conditional, or rather, the basic calculation itself is already conditional on the model being true.

Answer (score 2):

You can say $P(X_{min} > 1) = (1-F(1))^{15}$ since you want all five samples to exceed $1$

If the density is $f(x)= \frac1\lambda e^{-x/\lambda}$ then $F(x)=1-e^{-x/\lambda}$, so $$P\left(X_{min} > 1 \mid \lambda = \tfrac15\right) = \left(e^{-1/5}\right)^{15}=e^{-3} \approx 0.049787$$ as you seem to have found by another approach

Comment: So the approach I mentioned under Roberts comment is also correct? Because I am not sure whether or not I have to divide by the conditional probability?

Comment: Or is it because $P(A|B) = P(A)$ because $X_i$ comes from a random sample which by definition consists of i.d.d. samples?

Comment: @Mathias You not treating $H_0$ as an event with a probability, and you were dealing with the probability density rather than proportional to it, so your denominator integral was going to be $1$ and so was unnecessary; if it was not going to be $1$ then you might need to do it.  But my answer was designed to avoid any integration